Connecting to HubSpot through Snaplogic Rest API
I am attempting to connect to Hubspot using a Rest API Get.  An account in Hubspot was set up for me as I do not have access to that portion.   They created a Rest Dynamic OAuth2 Account using a Bearer token.  The account in hubspot is set up using the Private Apps guidance in developers.hubspot.com.  When I link the account to the Rest Snap and place my url I get the following error message:

REST API service endpoint returned error result: status code = 401, reason phrase = Unauthorized, refer to the error_entity field in the error view document for more details

Am I missing something in my configuration?  or is this a firewall issue?  What does this error mean?
Help!

I found the solution.  The 'Header authenticated' checkbox needed to be checked in the account.  I checked it and saved it and now I am getting data.

Here are some common reasons for this error and steps to troubleshoot it:

Incorrect or Expired Bearer Token
Incorrect URL
Missing or Misconfigured Headers

